# After reordering cell is behind another cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a reorder indicator. So what I'm trying to do is that when the user is dragging the cell. That on the place the user wants to drop the cell an other cell is added with a background. I already achieved that. But when the user drops the cell, the indicator cell needs to be deleted and the table must stay the same like the user intended to.

Now I have the following problem. When the user drops the cell. The indicator cell is correctly removed but the dropped cell is behind another cell suddenly.

Screenshots to clarify:

[image: Begin state]
[image: End state]
[image: View hierarchy in xcode in endstate]

My code:

```
import UIKit
import PureLayout

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(forAutoLayout: ())
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .SingleLine
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Default")
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Indicator")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        return tableView
    }()

    private var data: [Int] = [Int]()

    private var isIndicatorRowAddedInSection: Bool = false
    private var lastIndicatorRowIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

        self.tableView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero, excludingEdge: .Top)
        self.tableView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Top, withInset: 40)

        for index in 0..<20 {
            data.append(index)
        }

        self.tableView.editing = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if let lastIndexPath = self.lastIndicatorRowIndexPath {
            print("Need to delete a row on section \(lastIndexPath.section) row \(lastIndexPath.row)")
            self.isIndicatorRowAddedInSection = false
            self.lastIndicatorRowIndexPath = nil
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([lastIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }

        let itemToMove = self.data[fromIndexPath.row]
        self.data.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
        self.data.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return .None
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath,
                   toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath {

        if let lastIndexPath = self.lastIndicatorRowIndexPath {
            print("Target indexpath indexpath to delete row \(lastIndexPath.section) row \(lastIndexPath.row)")
            self.isIndicatorRowAddedInSection = false
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([lastIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()

            self.lastIndicatorRowIndexPath = nil
        }

        self.isIndicatorRowAddedInSection = true

        self.lastIndicatorRowIndexPath = proposedDestinationIndexPath

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        print("Indicator view inserted at section \(proposedDestinationIndexPath.section) row \(proposedDestinationIndexPath.row)")
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: proposedDestinationIndexPath.row, inSection: proposedDestinationIndexPath.section)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        return proposedDestinationIndexPath
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.isIndicatorRowAddedInSection {
            return self.data.count + 1
        }
        return self.data.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let indicatorIndexPath = self.lastIndicatorRowIndexPath where isIndicatorRowAddedInSection {
            if indicatorIndexPath.section == indexPath.section && indicatorIndexPath.row == indexPath.row {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Indicator", forIndexPath: indexPath)

                return cell
            }
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Default", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = String(self.data[indexPath.row])
        return cell

    }
}
```

I don't see the problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: I do not see the problem yet - why does the view order of the cells matter? Does it have any negative effect on your application?

Comment: It's now created as example with numbers but the actual data set is different. The user has the ability to reorder and that order is saved to a backend. But the only problem I know still have is that the dropped cell is behind another cell that's the only thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In the moveRow it is executed on Thread 1 (main thread) but it seems like it's not. Because when you wrap it with a dispatch async to the main thread it just works.

Full working code:

```
import UIKit
import PureLayout

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(forAutoLayout: ())
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .SingleLine
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Default")
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Indicator")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        return tableView
    }()

    private var data: [Int] = [Int]()

    private var isIndicatorRowAddedInSection: Bool = false
    private var lastIndicatorRowIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

        self.tableView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero, excludingEdge: .Top)
        self.tableView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Top, withInset: 40)

        for index in 0..<5 {
            data.append(index)
        }

        self.tableView.editing = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        let itemToMove = self.data[fromIndexPath.row]
        self.data.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
        self.data.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: toIndexPath.row - 1)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if let lastIndexPath = self.lastIndicatorRowIndexPath {
                print("Need to delete a row on section \(lastIndexPath.section) row \(lastIndexPath.row)")
                self.isIndicatorRowAddedInSection = false
                self.lastIndicatorRowIndexPath = nil
                tableView.beginUpdates()

                // Need to put some logic if you pull to top it has to be + 1
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: lastIndexPath.row - 1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        })
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return .None
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath,
                   toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath {

        if let lastIndexPath = self.lastIndicatorRowIndexPath {
            print("Target indexpath indexpath to delete row \(lastIndexPath.section) row \(lastIndexPath.row)")
            self.isIndicatorRowAddedInSection = false
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([lastIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
            tableView.endUpdates()

            self.lastIndicatorRowIndexPath = nil
        }

        self.isIndicatorRowAddedInSection = true

        self.lastIndicatorRowIndexPath = proposedDestinationIndexPath

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        print("Indicator view inserted at section \(proposedDestinationIndexPath.section) row \(proposedDestinationIndexPath.row)")
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: proposedDestinationIndexPath.row, inSection: proposedDestinationIndexPath.section)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        return proposedDestinationIndexPath
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.isIndicatorRowAddedInSection {
            return self.data.count + 1
        }
        return self.data.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let indicatorIndexPath = self.lastIndicatorRowIndexPath where isIndicatorRowAddedInSection {
            if indicatorIndexPath.section == indexPath.section && indicatorIndexPath.row == indexPath.row {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Indicator", forIndexPath: indexPath)
                cell.textLabel?.text = "IndicatorView: ROW \(indexPath.row) SECTION = \(indexPath.section)"
                print("Indictorview cell for row")
                return cell
            }
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Default", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "ROW = \(indexPath.row) SECTION = \(indexPath.section)"
        return cell

    }
}
```